# homogeneous differential equation in polar coordinates : proof with Newton's notation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I want to solve a problem [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572554/homogeneous-differential-equation-in-polar-coordinates) on MSE, but I want to use Newton's notation and be careful on every assumption I make at every step, so this is not a duplicate.

I restate the problem :

> Given an homogeneous differential equation $y' = f(x,y)$, rewrite it in polar coordinates and show it becomes separable.

Attempt :

first I can pass to polar coordinates with

$$x= r \cos \theta$$
$$y= r \sin \theta$$

Substituting in the r.h.s. we get

$$f(x,y) = f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) $$

so **when** $r \neq 0$, since the d.e. is homogeneous ($f(x,y) = f(tx,ty)$ for every $t \neq 0$) I obtain

$$f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = f(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = g(\theta) $$

The assumption that $r \neq 0 $ is fulfilled whenever the function $y(x)$ (which is supposed to exist) is defined on any open set, because in this case there exists an interval where $r$ is never $0$ which is what we want so I continue.

For the l.h.s. instead **I suppose that a function $r(\theta)$ exists**, so that I can differentiate with respect to $\theta$, then

$$x'(\theta) = r'(\theta) \cos \theta - r(\theta) \sin \theta$$
$$y'(\theta)= r'(\theta) \sin \theta + r(\theta) \cos \theta $$

Because the function $y(x)$ is supposed to exist then it exists also $y(x(\theta)) = y(r(\theta)\cos(\theta))$ then

$$[y(x(\theta))]' = y'(x(\theta)) [x(\theta)]' $$

I tried to follow the same path of the answer to the other question but (without the hidden help of Leibniz's notation) I don't know how to continue. Maybe there is more than meets the eye in the passages involving Leibniz's notation in the linked question. I don't know if the question is somewhat related to differential geometry but I didn't study this subject yet.

Can someone provide a proof in Newton's notation and which deals with every 'edge case' ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'm unclear as to how you obtain $$f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = f(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = g(\theta) $$. 
 This would appear to be true only around the circle of constant radius equal to $r$. I don't see how you can prove that it's separable for an arbitrary functional form $f(x,y)$

Comment: Consider that it is an homogeneous differential equation

Comment: OK. I'll have to think about this a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just lost dependence of $y$ from $x$ trasforming in polar coordinates.

Since we suppose $y(x)$ exists and also $r(\theta)$ exists then I have $$y(x(\theta)) = r \sin \theta $$ from which follows that $$[y(x(\theta))]' = r' \sin\theta - r \cos(\theta)$$

fron here the proof is the same as in the other post